# Configure adapter in Model

Tags: sails.js

I use sails 0.9.
Here is adapters.js code:

```
module.exports.adapters = {

mongo: {
  module: 'sails-mongo',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: 'tracker'
},

mongo2: {
  module: 'sails-mongo',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  user: '',
  password: '',
}
};
```

And model:

```
module.exports = {

adapter: 'mongo2',

config: {
  database: 'offer'
},

attributes: {

  name: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: true,
    required: true
    }
}
};
```

From docs http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models i get that this model will be saved in database named "offer", but it use db named "sails". Looks like its just ignore config section of model.
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the database in adapter config itself

```
mongo2: {
  module: 'sails-mongo',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: 'offer'
}
```